# Is there any single line C library function which takes very large time?

Tags: c, performance

I want to calculate performance gain on distributed system. However I can only execute a single line of code on a single core. So to calculate the speedup of operation I want a single line code that takes significantly large time to execute.

Basically I want a compute intensive C library function that takes significant time.

Let us say I have a code the function `fun` in the example can be executed on two different cores

```
int fun(){
  // one line of code ; one line of code means I want a single C
  // statement which can be a library function or complex math operation
}

int main() {
  int res1, res2;

  res1 = fun();
  res2 = fun();
  return 0;
}
```

PS: I am writing C code. I cannot use `sleep()` or loops.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<10000000;i++){}`?

Comment: I can not use loops :(

Comment: large time or large CPU usage?

Comment: It should take large amount of time to execute and not the CPU usage.

Comment: How exactly is this one line's execution going to be distributed? And can't you just mash 200 statements onto one line?

Comment: how long is a significant amount of time?

Comment: This question is nonsense. You cannot "calculate performance gain on distributed system" by artificially introducing a limitation based on "a single line of code" that takes "significant time to perform" where "sleep()" is not acceptable. "I want to produce a line of code that is stupid but but you can't use code that is stupid" is meaningless.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this question. OP is asking for a function that takes a while to run so it can be used to test the performance of a system. Obviously, sleep functions won't do that (though I'm not sure why loops can't be used). Am I missing something?

Comment: @KSFT: It asks for a single line of code, which is a bizarre limitation (after all, that line could be 200 statements with no line breaks or one call to a crazy complicated function), and it specifies that the line will be run on a single core, which means it will specifically refuse to take advantage of the distributed system's benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand (leaving out the intricacies of distributed computing), all the OP really wants is a C library function that can help measure the performance perhaps in FLOPS. Check out some high precision libraries like MPC (http://www.multiprecision.org/index.php?prog=cm) which may help you benchmark if that is what you are seeking.

Answer (score -1):

the sleep() and related functions: nanosleep(), usleep(), etc) can allow the current process to delay for any desired (within reason) amount of time